# Evaluate $\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2} \min (\sin x, \frac{1}{2}) dx$

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

> Evaluate
>   $\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}  \min (\sin x, \frac{1}{2}) dx$

Now, what I've tried to do is to write $\min (\sin x, \frac{1}{2})$     :  $\sin x \leq \frac{1}{2}$ and $\frac{1}{2} < \sin x$. but I don't quite understand how to choose the sets for each minimum (because I know that I will have to split this integral.)

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: $\sin x\leq\frac{1}{2}$ when $0\leq x\leq\frac{\pi}{6}$. Try drawing the graph of the integrand.

Comment: Jon9, please use `\sin x` or `\sin(x)`, ditto for most trig functions (backslash immediately receding the trig function).  Also, when referring to yourself, use `I` and not `i`.  But thanks for using mathjax; you've done a great job in most of the formatting here!

Comment: @ amWhy, I am sorry . I am actually in a hurry( I know I should write this when I am not, but I was curious to see an answer) but I will make sure to not repeat the same mistakes, next time. Thank you for letting me know !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice two things:

1. On the interval $(0,\frac{\pi}{2})$, function $\sin{x}$ is always increasing.
2. $\sin(0) =0$

That means that $\min \left(\sin x, \frac{1}{2} \right)$ will be equal to $\sin x$ when $x<\frac{\pi}{6}$ because $\sin{\frac{\pi}{6}}=\frac{1}{2}$. Now we have

$$
\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \min \left(\sin x, \frac{1}{2} \right) dx = \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{6}} \sin x dx + \int_{\frac{\pi}{6}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{1}{2} dx = \frac{1}{6} \left( -3 \sqrt{3} + \pi + 6 \right)
$$

Answer (score 2):

$\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \min(\sin x,\frac{1}{2})dx=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{6}}\sin x\space dx+\int_{\frac{\pi}{6}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\dfrac{1}{2}\space dx=1-\dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{2}+\dfrac{\pi}{6}$